# Creating a GeoTIFF with PNG & XML

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, xml, png

I want to make a GeoTIFF file to use in a navigation app. What I currently have is a PNG with the map and a XML that goes along with it. Does anyone know how to somehow combine them and export it as a GeoTIFF?

Comment: depends on what is in the XML file?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Questions here need to contain all the information necessary to answer the Question. Please [Edit] the Question to indicate what is in the PNG, and what the XML contains (if it's a birthday party picture and a list of gifts in XML, you can't make a GeoTIFF from it). Also, navigation is usually a vector process, so you might want to think about how a GeoTIFF would even help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your `PNG` is a raster map and the `XML` file contains the georeferencing information.
Try loading the `PNG` file in `QGIS` using `Add Raster Layer`.

If the `XML` file contains georeferencing information for the `PNG` file, it will be automatically read by `QGIS` and will create a georeferenced raster layer. Right click on this layer and Export it to `GeoTIFF`.

In case your `XML` file does not contain georeferencing information, you can try georeferencing the `PNG` file using `Georeferencer` (given you have some reference points on the map, like grid line intersections). From `Georeferencer` you can directly save the image as `GeoTIFF`.

Comment: Here is what the XML file contained: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pH1myTCYqUjgJT5kMNdENkRdxP6gm3IfQuTNC0FH2_s/edit?usp=sharing I also tried to put both the map and the file in the same folder with the same name and import it into QGIS but i didn´t work. When i tried with another PNG with a PGW file it worked as it should. Is there any way to convert the data in the XML file into a PGW file?

Comment: The file you shared is the `aux.xml` file associated with `GeoTIFF` files. This does not contain any information you need for `.pgw` file. If you have the original `.TIFF` file, then open it in `QGIS` and go to `Information` in `Properties`. Find the `Origin` and `Pixel Size` parameters. These will be in x,y format. Now make the `.pgw file` using a text editor, in the following format:  
`Pixel Size`(x)  
0.0000  
0.0000  
'Pixel Size'(y)   
`Origin`(x)  
`Origin`(y)  
eg:  
1.085196999397  
0.000000000  
0.000000000  
-1.085185275323  
665043.952853597468  3486958.665822010953

Comment: The aux.xml files can contain extra information about .png files but the issue is that this certain aux.xml file contains only the image statistics (min, max, avg values of each band).